# MS Access Filter by ComboBox selection based on Column names

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am a bit stuck here. i have got the following code:

```
` Private Sub Command88_Click()
Dim filterString As String
Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String

startDate = txtStartDate
endDate = txtEndDate
selectedfield = CboxSelectField.Value

filterString = "[HW End of Support] BETWEEN #" & Format(startDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & Format(endDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"

Me.Filter = filterString
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub`
```

the filter runs fine as long as the value of the column to filter on by remains hard coded i.e `[HW End of Support]` but i have a combobox called `CboxSelectField` that has 4 different column names and what i need is to filter data based on the column that has been selected from the combo box?
if i replace the `[HW End of Support]` with the `selectedField` variable that contains the value of the selection of the combobox then the code breaks and it does not filter.

help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

`filterString = "" & "[" & selectedField & "]" & " BETWEEN #" & Format(startDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & Format(endDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"`

Comment: This is just a more convoluted way to create a string identical to my answer.

Comment: Why all the extra concatenation? And why are you starting the string off with an empty string, followed by another string? Seems like an awful lot of double handling...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined `"selectedfield"` - you should define it as a `string`, and then set it to `"[" & CboxSelectField.Value & "]"` to make it work the way you're trying to at the moment.

So your coding would look like this:

```
Private Sub Command88_Click()
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String
Dim selectedfield As String, filterString As String

startDate = txtStartDate
endDate = txtEndDate
selectedfield = "[" & CboxSelectField.Value & "]"

filterString = selectedfield & " BETWEEN #" & _
Format(startDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & _
Format(endDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"

Me.Filter = filterString
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with:

```
filterString = "[" & selectedfield  & "] BETWEEN #" & Format(startDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & Format(endDate, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"
```

This will output for a field name of "My Field":

```
[My Field] BETWEEN #04-25-2018# And #04-25-2018#
```

Your expanded expression will return:

```
[My Field] BETWEEN #04-25-2018# And #04-25-2018#
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding like I'm telling people how to vote, (which I'm not, just curious why they're voting the way they are): While I prefer my answer, feel it's more complete and neater, I don't understand what about this answer is "not helpful"... It looks right (and based on the currently selected answer would definitely work)... so...

Comment: @IsaacReefman: Originally, Raul didn't tell that the field name included spaces, thus bracketing was not needed. Then he did, and posted a clumsy string concatenating, thus I modified my answer to include the bracketing in the usual way. Still, a comment to my answer could have done it, and - you are right - I see no reason for the shy and anonymous downvotes. But that's life.

Comment: Another mystery: He selected my answer (that had the brackets in from the beginning, and would have returned the same result as yours, just structured it differently) and that was it for ages. And then he changed his mind and switched to his... I genuinely wonder why the sudden change.